# CCMenuitem Multi Line?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, line, menuitem, multiline, break

Is there a way to make a Menuitem multiline?
i tried

```
CCMenuItemFont mapPacks = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Map\n Packs" target:self selector:@selector(mapPacks:)];
```

but that doesn`t seem to work

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the '*' after CCMenuItemFont in your code snippet. 
I use labels for creating multiline items, like this:

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Map\n Packs" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 100) 
                                           alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter 
                                           fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:22];
CCMenuItemFont *mapPacks = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithLabel:label target:self selector:@selector(mapPacks:)];
```